# netnamedpipebinding Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible

Tags: wcf

```
<services>          
      <service name="WcfServiceApplication.WallService" behaviorConfiguration="mex" >
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost:10042/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="WallService.svc"
                  binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="basic" name="Basic"
                  contract="WcfServiceApplication.IWallService"></endpoint>        
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexNamedPipeBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netNamedPipeBinding>
        <binding name="basic"></binding>
      </netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mex">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by troubleshooting and have resolved it.
Service should be hosted in a process and then be called.